# Creating and rendering an image dynamically with transparent background for use with drawImage

Tags: java, image, transparency, render, draw

Could someone provide an example of how to dynamically create an image in Java, draw lines et cetera on it, and then draw the image so that areas not painted will remain transparent in the drawing process?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One could use a [`BufferedImage`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html) with an image type that supports transparency such as [`BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#TYPE_INT_ARGB):

```
BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(100, 100, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
```

One can draw on the `BufferedImage` by calling [`BufferedImage.createGraphics`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#createGraphics()) to obtain a `Graphics2D` object, then perform some drawing:

```
BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(100, 100, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

Graphics2D g = img.createGraphics();
g.drawLine(0, 0, 10, 10);  // draw a line.
g.dispose();
```

Then, since `BufferedImage` is a subclass of [`Image`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Image.html) that can be used to draw onto another `Image` using one of the [`Graphics.drawImage`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#drawImage(java.awt.Image,%20int,%20int,%20java.awt.image.ImageObserver)) that accepts an `Image`.

Comment: Thank you so much! It was very frustrating when a normal image object was not doing the job. My roommate looked at me weirdly after the much rejoicing from seeing it work correctly. :-)